# How can I bold two words around a string within a string, but not overlap sentences?

Tags: php, string, text

I need to bold a search term and its context (within a sentence).

Consider the string:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetuer adipiscing elit.

If the search term is `Lorem ipsum`, then the result should be:

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit** amet. Consectetuer adipiscing elit.

If the search is `dolor sit`, the result should be:

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.** Consectetuer adipiscing elit.

If the search is `Consectetuer`, the result should be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. **Consectetuer adipiscing elit.**

How do you recommend I do this (in php)?

Bolding the search term is easy enough:

```
$string = str_replace($query,'<strong>' . $query . '</strong>', $string);
```

But how can I include two words before and after without overlapping to the next or previous sentence?

Comment: How much of the "context" do you want to bold? It seems like you want the surrounding couple of words?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, David.  Two words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the string into "sentences" (split on a full stop (what about exclamation marks, question marks, ...)).

Then find the sentence with the matching word.

Then split that sentence into "words" and add some tags in two words before and after the matching word. Since you only have one sentence to work on, you'd include a check to make sure you didn't go out of bounds of the word array.

Then join the words back together, and join all the sentences back together.

---

Alternatively, you could use regex and [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (although that may not be a road you want to go down, especially if you have an option such as splitting on plaintext - there's a quote that goes something like "You have a problem and you want to use regex for it. Now you have two problems."):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\b(\\w+ +){0,2}$query( +\\w+){0,2}\\b/i",
                       '<strong>$0</strong>',
                       $string);
```

The regex works like this (backslashes are escaped above):

```
\b        | match a word boundary (ie match whole words)
(\w+ +)   | match a "word" followed by spaces (to separate it from the next word)
{0,2}     | match 0 to 2 of these such words (it will match as many as possible
          | up to 2)
$query    | match the '$query' string
( +\w+)   | regex for space (separating $query) followed by a word
{0,2}     | match 0 to 2 of these words (as many as possible up to 2)
\b        | match a word boundary (ie match whole words)
```

The `/i` at the end means "case insensitive".

The replacement string, `<strong>$0</strong>`, means to replace with all the matched words surrounded by the 'strong' tags.

The reason this works is that **the regular expression does not allow a full stop to be matched**. So it will grab *up to* 2 words either side of `$query` but is forbidden from going over full stops.

There are the usual caveats (that you would have with any method you used) -- do you want the bolding to go over question marks? exclamation marks? Is an apostrophe allowed in a word? What will you do about non-full-stop punctuation between words? etc.

I'd recommend refining the above regex (if you want to use regex, that is) to:

- allow apostrophes in a word: change `\w+` to `[\w']+` (escape your for PHP backslashes too)
- allow various punctuation symbols *between* words: change the `+` to something like `[\s\-&,]+` (means "space", "-", "&", "," are allowed between words -- add more to your liking, but don't put "." in to prevent the bold-ing from going over full stops).

Comment: Your answer works perfectly without the added refinements in your last two bullets. But for the life of me I cannot make the added refinements work. Would you mind demonstrating how they would work in the pattern? Thanks. Here's my blank pattern that works (as above) : $pattern = "/\\b(\\w+ +){0,2}$needle( +\\w+){0,2}\\b/i"; I've tried all sorts of combinations of /\\b([\w']+ +){0,2} and /\\b([\w'][\s\-&,]+ +){0,2}. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Basically you would change the ` +` in the regex to `[\s\-&]+` and all the `\w+` to `[\w']+` -- additionally, you need to escape your backslashes since you're using PHP! You can experiment with regex [here](http://regexr.com?303ma) (regexr is a very handy site). Good luck!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  Actually it was the double backslashes that were getting me in trouble.  Singles worked fine.  Working snippet: $pattern = "/\b(['\w]+[&,\-\s]+){0,2}$needle([&,\-\s]+['\w]+){0,2}\b/i"; echo preg_replace($pattern,'<strong>$0</strong>',$string);

Comment: Hey MC, I just noticed that when the needle is plural in the haystack, the needle is not found.  Can you suggest an improvement to allow for plural needles? Ex. needle = "lorem", but haystack says "lorems ipsum".

Comment: Try replacing `$query` with `$querys?` which allows it to be followed by an optional s. (won't handle plurals that aren't just appending an 's' to the word though, like octopus->octopi, foot->feet, dwarf->dwarves, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
$str ="your whole string ";
if(isset($_POST['searchStr']))
{
$searchStr= $_POST['searchStr'];
$str= str_replace($searchStr,'<b>'. $searchStr.'</b>',$str);
}
echo "$str";
```

if you want a case -insensitive replacement use below function

```
    str_ireplace() - Case-insensitive version of str_replace.
```