# How can I find a plural needle in haystack with preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here's my [awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372724/how-can-i-bold-two-words-around-a-string-within-a-string-but-not-overlap-senten/9372923#9372923) summarize string function:

```
function summarize($haystack, $needle, $wordLimit=1) {
    $preg_safe = str_replace(" ", "\s", preg_quote($needle));
    $pattern = "/(\w*\S\s+){0,$wordLimit}\S*\b($preg_safe)\b\S*(\s\S+){0,$wordLimit}/ix";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches)) {
        return $matches[0][0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function looks for the needle in a large string and returns it along with *n* words of context around the needle.  Sort of like how Google search results show the string of your search in context of the result under the title.

Here's how I use it:

```
$haystack = 'Lorem ipsums dolor sit amet.'; // note the plural "ipsum"

echo summarize($haystack,'ipsums');
```

Returns: `Lorem ipsums dolor` *(defaults to 1 word around the needle)*

```
echo summarize($haystack,'ipsum'); // i.e. not exact word match of "ipsums"
```

Returns: `false`

How can I adjust the regex to return the same result the exact word match?

Comment: What's the plural of "ox"? Is it "oxs"? Clue: No. How do you plan to handle that?

Comment: You could always run the input needle through a pluralization function.  Nethack has an... interesting one: http://celabs.com/nethack/html/objnam_8c.html#ac1ac6c9f4a8707e6d675c75cf9bd4908    =)

Comment: Don't you just want to take out the `\b`'s, so you don't require word boundaries right next to the search string?

Comment: @RussellZahniser Then `summarize($haystack, 'sum')` would return `Lorem ipsums dolor`, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: @Ryan: Are you trying to match other forms of the word ("man" would also match "men") or are you trying to match parts of a word ("fit" would match "benefit")?

Comment: @cbuckley correct, ideally sum wouldn't match ipsums.  But Russell brings up a good point about non-s plurals (man vs. men).  Let's say man vs. men isn't critical.  Only plural "s".  So ipsum matches ipsums but sum does not match ipsums.  What do you think?

Comment: The plural of `ipsum` is `ipsa`. Also, the plural of `sum` is `sumus`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to pass your example you could simply allow an optional `s` at the end of the word. Eg:

```
"/(\w*\S\s+){0,$wordLimit}\S*\b(${preg_safe}s?)\b\S*(\s\S+){0,$wordLimit}/ix"
```

But that's probably not enough.