# How to extract only two words around string and replace the others by "..."?

Tags: php, regex, string, text

I am trying to make bold two words around a particular string like in question [How can I bold two words around a string within a string, but not overlap sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372724/how-can-i-bold-two-words-around-a-string-within-a-string-but-not-overlap-senten)

the solution was given as

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\b(\\w+ +){0,2}$query( +\\w+){0,2}\\b/i",
                       '<strong>$0</strong>',
                       $string);
```

Which works fine for me, however, I want to make the other strings (the not bold ones) be replaced by "..." for example consider the string

```
$string = 'Then split that sentence into words and add some tags in two words before and after the matching word. 
Since you only have one sentence to work on, you\'d include a check to make sure you didn\'t go out of bounds of the word array.
Sometimes you need to disable/enable the form element like input or textarea. Jquery helps you to easily make this with setting disabled attribute';
```

could this be made to look, if I was search for the word "the", as

> ... **and after the matching word** ... 
>   **bounds of the word array**
>   ...**disable/enable the form element**...

Also one drawback of this solution is that it only searchs for strings between two spaces. Could this be modified so that it searches for any strings?

Finally, could we set a limit on the number of searches that could be found so that if was searching again for the string "the" in the previous text and I set the limit to one I should only get

> ... **and after the matching word** ...

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps, [`'/.*?\b((?:\w+[\p{Zs}\p{P}]+){0,2}the(?:[\p{Zs}\p{P}]+\w+){0,2}\b)[^.!?]*/is'`](https://regex101.com/r/wW9dF0/3). Or [`.*?\b((?:\w+[\p{Zs}\p{P}]+){0,2}the(?: +\w+){0,2}\b)[^.!?]*`](https://regex101.com/r/wW9dF0/1).

Comment: Limiting searches to 1 is done with `preg_match`.

Comment: @stribizhev, both your suggestions give `Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in...`

Comment: No idea how you tested, but since you are interested, here is [my demo](http://ideone.com/JpwcCD).

Comment: with this regex  instead of `disable/enable the form element` you will get `to disable/enable the form element` if it is set to match `/`.Is that a problem for you?

Comment: @stribizhev, why is the string `Jquery helps you to easily make this with setting disabled attribute` still added at the end? Also, this only searches for strings between spaces.

Comment: @AruneshSingh, which regex?

Comment: Why only between spaces? `disable/enable` are not. Also, the sentence you mention does not contain the key word, thus it remains.

Comment: @stribizhev, I mean the search string may not be a word like "the" or several words, but it may be a part of a word or other string.

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/0jZn8m). Note it does not account for abbreviated words like `e.g.`, `i.e.`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx are powerfull but sometimes you need some more code than this.
The function `sentence_split` will do what you want.

```
$string = 'Then split that sentence into words and add some tags in two words before and after the matching word. 
Since you only have one sentence to work on, you\'d include a check to make sure you didn\'t go out of bounds of the word array.
Sometimes you need to disable/enable the form element like input or textarea. Jquery helps you to easily make this with setting disabled attribute';
$query = "the";


function sentence_split($text, $query, $limit = null, $delimiter=" "){
    preg_match_all("/\b([\/\w]+$delimiter){0,2}$query($delimiter\w+){0,2}\b/i", $text, $result);
    if(!is_null($limit)){
    $result[0] = array_slice($result[0], 0, $limit);    
    }
    return "... <strong>".implode($result[0],"</strong> ... <strong>") . "</strong> ...";
}


var_dump(sentence_split($string, $query);
```

Outputs:

... **and after the matching word** ... **bounds of the word array** ... **to disable/enable the form element** ...

OR

```
var_dump(sentence_split($string, $query, 2);
```

output

... **and after the matching word** ... **bounds of the word array** ...

With the fourth parameter "$delimiter" you can play around. It's not quite possible to set delimiter to emtpy string as it will break the desired results.

But we are all here to play :)

Problem I saw after posting is the string "disable/enable". For the current version of `sentence_split` this is one word. Therefore it also outputs the word before. Treating this as two words would make the whole thing much more complicated.

Comment: This is great, but it only works when you are searching for a word or a string between two spaces, for example if you search for word "sentence", you'll get two results however if you search for "sent" or "entenc" or "sentence int" you'll get no result. Could this be fixed?

Comment: With some extra work this could be fixed! However my provided function does what you asked for in first place. To split without spaces would be very hard with only regEx I think! 
Why the downvote ?